# A redirect doesn't work in user form

Tags: 8

The project it's in Drupal 8.2

Hello, when a user fill the profile and Save  ( /user/id/edit) the page it's reloaded with the new data in the same url, but I want to redirect the user to /user/id

This code should work:

```
function custom_user_form_user_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
}
```

But it doesn't work, any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Is this code called ? How is your module named ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set a redirect directly in the form alter. Submit callbacks are responsible for setting a redirect. You need to add a submit callback on the button after the default one and then set the redirect there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a new submit handler to the form:

```
function custom_user_form_user_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_submit_handler';
}
```

Inside the new submit handler set the redirect:

```
function custom_user_submit_handler(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
}
```

Comment: Hello Colin, thank for the example, at the end you say the same that Berdir, but he answered first, it's why I give him the ok status.

Answer (score 0):

In this case this is the correct code to make it works.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_id_alter()
 */
function custom_user_form_user_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]= 'custom_user_custom_submit_handler';
}

/**
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function custom_user_custom_submit_handler(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form_state->setRedirect('user.page');
}
```

Thanks to Berdir and Colin by their helps.